# iOS Facebook share video Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am looking for a way to share a video of my application on Facebook.
I installed the SDK to facebook and followed the instructions but I do not understand why I can not share my video.

```
let fbVideo:FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()
fbVideo.videoURL = url
let content: FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
content.video = fbVideo
FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

I have one error with the parameter delegate :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ShareViewController' to expected argument type 'FBSDKSharingDelegate!'
```

Note that I am in my class ShareViewController.

There are no other means to share a video on facebook ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The method `showFromViewController:withContent:delegate:` expects the delegate argument to be of type `FBSDKSharingDelegate`. You are providing a value of type `ShareViewController` not `FBSDKSharingDelegate` which means said view controller does not conform to that type. You would need to make your view controller to conform to type `FBSDKSharingDelegate`. As an example:

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKSharingDelegate {
    // code
}
```

Or pass in another object that conforms to type `FBSDKSharingDelegate`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But when I try to implement the module FBSDKSharingDelegate, my class said she does not conform. I have not (to my knowledge) of object  to type FBSDKSharingDelegate

Comment: @Aaron - I cannot figure out how to get video to share either, but make sure you have FBSDKShareKit imported into your file and you have included the sharer functions. They should be suggested with an error and you can automatically pop them in with the error's "Fix" button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `FBSDKSharingDelegate` protocol and it's methods.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController ,FBSDKSharingDelegate{

    //add following methods to the class:
func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
            print("Completed");
        }


        func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
            print("Failed with error : \(error.localizedDescription)");
        }

        func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
            print("Cancelled")
        }

    }
```